# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeppavlov' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I've created a virtual enviornment (deepnlp) and installed the deeppavlov package in the virtual env. I could run "import deeppavlov" without any problem on the command line in the env. But when I tried to do the same thing ('import deeppavlov') in the jupyter notebook, in the kernel 'deepnlp', but I got the error mesaage:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeppavlov'

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found out the solution? This problem may or may have to do with the package 'deeppavlov'. It could be because something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, installing a package to virtualenv has nothing to do with your Jupyter (unless the same interpreter is used in both cases). The solution would be to run the following command in jupyter cell:

`import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user deeppavlov`